# jQuery Tabs "Undefined is Not a Function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs

I've recently been trying to use or familiarize myself with the JQuery tabs function. However everytime I've tried using it I get the error "undefined is not a function". I've researched this problem and a lot say it may have to do with the .js file not being loaded but that is not the case as my console tab shows it being loaded.

Here is the HTML file I have been trying to test out:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Portal.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Portal.js"></script>  
    <script src="tabs.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


    <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#tab1'>Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab2'>Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#tab3'>Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id='tab1'>
       <p>Hi, this is the first tab.</p>
  </div>
  <div id='tab2'>
    <p>This is the 2nd tab.</p>
      </div>
     <div id='tab3'>
                   <p>And this is the 3rd tab.</p>
             </div>
               </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And the tabs.js file (which throws the undefined error when debugging):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("div.tabs").tabs();
});
```

Thanks. I can provide more details if needed. No CSS is being used yet (but I don't believe that to be the issue here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting class tabs but what you have is ID tabs.

Change it to:

```
$( 'div#tabs' ).tabs();
```

Or change your HTML to:

```
class="tabs"
```

Comment: Side note: `$('#tabs')` will be faster.

Comment: Have you load the tabs() plugin code? If you do, can you tell where/which code throws the error?

Answer (score 2):

Make really sure, that you are loading the js from the external sources.

I had a similar problem. My code was working in konqueror, opera  and some firefox / iceweasel browsers, but not in others and not in chromium.

It turned out, that while my page was https hosted, i tried to load the external js over insecure http connection. These links were silently discarded by the "not working" browsers... i spent hours on that frack.

Hope this helps you or others.

Answer (score 1):

`$( "#tabs" ).tabs()` use this instead of  `$("div.tabs").tabs()`